# Load javascript after 5 seconds after page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried the following:

```
<body id="myBody" onload = "setTimeout('a()', 5000)" / >
```

Is this the correct method? The reason why I want to do this is because I have my entire website animating in (such as fade ins) on page load. Having my javascript only makes the animation unsmooth.

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: yours was the correct way for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    animation();
    setTimeout(otherOperation, 5000);
}, false);

function animation() {}
function otherOperation() {}
```

maybe you can use code like this

Comment: so if I copy this code and add it in a script tag inside the head of my document it would work right?

Answer (score 6):

This code will work. Just set your time in milliseconds and write your JS code on loadAfterTime function:

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
   setTimeout(loadAfterTime, 5000)
};


function loadAfterTime() { 
// code you need to execute goes here. 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<body id="myBody" onload = "setTimeout(a, 5000)">`
Try this

Comment: simply and effective, not sure why hasn't been voted to the top.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery your animation has a callback that you can use to delay the firing of all other javascript events like so:

```
$( window ).on( 'load', function () {

    $( '.someElements' ).animate({

        // properties to animate
    }, 300, function () {

        initScripts();
    });
});

function initScripts () {
  // call all other functions here
}
```

Comment: I use css animations but jquery for other animations which I want fired 5 seconds after my page fade-in.

Answer (score -1):

The Browser is always load all of your script if any when you open the web page. So It depend on when you call your javascript functions. 
Try this:

```
document.ready(function(){ 
 // your code
});
or
$(function(){
     // your code
});
```

both of them make sure that all of element on your page have been loaded.